# Regular expression to get text between Indicator and Tag

Tags: python, regex

I have a report of occurred errors generated from my program and now I want to create some kind of whitelist. Therefore I want to parse all errors which have the tag "@Whitelist"

So the report looks like this:

```
...
45)
Error: some description
Signal: lorem ipsum
@Whitelist

46)
Error: other description
Signal: lorem ipsum
File:   some file

47)
Error: lorem ipsum
Project: X
@Whitelist
@Comment description why this is sent to the whitelist
...
```

Here I want to have the Error Nr 45 and 47, but not 46

Ok to sum this up:
I am trying to have a regular expression to get everything inbetween (including) the tag "Error" (which can be "Warning" or "Message" too) up to "@Comment" (including the comment tag with the message) and only if @Whitelist is present.

There can be N lines inbetween @Whitelist and the Error indicator

Actually I can't come up with a good solution for this problem, some professional out there? Many thanks in advance

Edit: I just realized that it could be possible that the report can change over time, for example there could be a headline added above a group of errors. Meaning: Error 46 and 47 have the same type, so there would be the line "File Read Errors: " above the Error 46. Thats why I wanted to have some kind of solution where I get the Error based on the Tag "Error|Warning|Message" and "@Whitelist"
I hope it is kind of clear what I mean with this

Comment: If `Whitelist` is present, is it guaranteed to lie between `Error` etc and `Comment` ?

Comment: @nodakai Yes, it has to be located right after the Error Message and right before the Comment tag

Comment: But the comment tag is not necessary present

Comment: A very inefficient one, just FYI: [`\d+\)\r?\n(Error(?:(?!Error|\n\d+\)).)*@Whitelist(?:(?!Error|\n\d+\)).)*)(?=$|\n\d+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/aD5xH5/1).

Comment: Hmm, when you say "up to `@Comment`", do you mean `@Comment` is included?  "Up to" is a very confusing English word.

Comment: @nodakai I edited the question, clearer now? Sorry I am not a native english speaker

Comment: @nodakai  
Thanks both of you, I created a good solution mixing up both of your solutions, thanks for bothering with my problem :)

Comment: @tobias_k
Thanks both of you, I created a good solution mixing up both of your solutions, thanks for bothering with my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

One of @op's requirement can be formulated as:

1. If an error item contains a line beginning with `@Comment`, anything following that line should be discarded
2. Otherwise, the output extends to the end of the input

I found it very difficult to fulfill this requirement and ended up with three regexes for:

1. Distinguishing each error item in the input
2. Extract items containing `Error:` etc and `@Whitelist` (and discard anything before `Error:` etc)
3. Process `@Comment` as stated above

http://ideone.com/E58Ihe

```
import re

splitter = re.compile(r'\n*(?=\d+\)\n)')
filter = re.compile(
    r'^(Error|Warning|Message):.*@Whitelist.*', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
cleanup = re.compile(r'(^@Comment[^\n]*).*', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
for chunk in splitter.split(input_str):
    m = filter.search(chunk)
    if m:
        output = cleanup.sub(r'\1', m.group(0))
        print("Output begin")
        print(output)
        print("Output end\n")
```

#### Original answer

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

> `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(Error|Warning|Message)[^)]*@Whitelist[^)]*(?=(@Comment|\n\n))')
for m in regex.finditer(input_str):
    print(m.group(0))

Error: some description
Signal: lorem ipsum
@Whitelist
Error: lorem ipsum
Project: X
@Whitelist
```

The idea is, each matching chunk should begin with either of `Error`, `Warning` or `Message`, contain `@Whitelist`, and end with either of `@Comment` or an empty line `\n\n` (but the ending part is excluded by the `(?=...)` feature.)

Note that `[^)]*` are used not to match against multiple chunks at once (according to your examples, each chunk begins with a number followed by `)`.)

Comment: Thanks for the response

It is working mostly as I wanted it, but I tested it and realized, what if the User wants to write something like this in the comment: "On whitelist because same error as Nr 49) " for example. Then the comment would not be included in the regex. Any suggestion how to fix this? I am not so good with regex

Comment: Thanks again for struggeling with this problem. One thing I don't really get about your teststring and regex(s) is, why this "Extra: should be included" text is included in Error 48

Comment: You wrote "get everything inbetween (including) the tag "Error" (which can be "Warning" or "Message" too) up to "@Comment" (including the comment tag with the message)" and "But the comment tag is not necessary present" so I understood everything after `Error` should be included when `@Comment` is not present

Answer (score 1):

How about this non-regex solution: Just split by double-newline (i.e. empty lines) and see whether that block contains `"@Whitelist"`:

```
for error in errors.split("\n\n"):
    if "\n@Whitelist" in error:
        print(error)
```

Or, if there are no blank lines actually, try this:

```
for error in re.split("\n(?=Error|Warning|Message)", errors):
    ...
```

IMHO, the more complex your error log becomes, the less likely a single regex is going to help you. Instead, you could use one regex for splitting the error messages and another regex for checking them, but currently not even that seems to be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response
I thought about this one too, but there i have the problem, if an error message contains this pattern too (there could be a longer message added later maybe) this solution would not do as expected

Comment: @Roke Well, in that case you could check `if "\n@Whitelist" in error:` (note the `\n`)

Comment: Well, there it starts with a lot of "Ifs" to check wheter the string is acceptable or not that's what I wanted to avoid. Also it wouldn't work if there were Headlines added to the report. That's why i thought a regex could prevent errors duo future changes on the report

Comment: @Roke I still see only one `if`. About those headlines: What headlines?

Comment: what if some headlines were added to the report later, like for each group of errors, a headline is above them...I will edit the post, sorry haven't thought about that one before actually

Comment: Then `split()`-ing with `\n*(?=\d+\)\n)` should work (split at a line containing only a number and a closing parenthesis) But you still need to discard anything after `@Comment` for strict conformance to your requirement.

Comment: @Roke Actually, I think the more complex your error log becomes, the less likely regexes are going to help you, or at least they'd become an unmaintainable mess of special characters. You can codify all (or some of) those ifs and conditions into the regex, but does that make it any better? Just my 2 cents.